# Wicket: BehaviorRequestTarget - component not enabled or visible; ignoring call

Tags: ajax, wicket

On one page I have added two panels, see figures `"select one or more"` and `"select one"`. The figure `"select one or more"` is the first `panel` that is visible to the user when the page is loaded for the first time. After the user makes some selections he/she can click the `next` button. Doing so, the other `panel` `"select one"` gets visible and the first panel gets invisible. Clicking on `back` button the first panel gets visible and the second panel disappears. Doing a selection on the second panel and clicking on next the page `"your selection"` gets open.

Everything works fine until I click on the back button of the `browser` from the second page `"your selection"` to the first page. Back on the first page the user sees the panel `"select one or more"` but nothing works. When I click on the checkboxes I see in the debug:

`BehaviorRequestTarget - component not enabled or visible; ignoring call. Component: [MarkupContainer [Component id = selection]]`

And when I click on the next button

`BehaviorRequestTarget - component not enabled or visible; ignoring call. Component: [MarkupContainer [Component id = next]]`

This is the ajax debug text:

`INFO: focus set on idb`

`INFO: Initiating Ajax POST request on ?wicket:interface=:2:allpopup:content:form:allItemsContainer:items:7:selectionContainer:selected::IBehaviorListener:0:&random=0.997746484662292`

`INFO: Invoking pre-call handler(s)...`

`INFO: Received ajax response (0 characters)`

`ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Could not find root <ajax-response> element`

`INFO: Invoking post-call handler(s)...`

`INFO: Invoking failure handler(s)...`

Any idea why this happen and what to do about it?

Thank you

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to my BasePage.java file (which extends WebPage) to force page reload when the back browser button is clicked.

```
// Sets page reload on browser back button
@Override
protected void configureResponse() {
    super.configureResponse();
    WebResponse response = getWebRequestCycle().getWebResponse();
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store");
    response.setHeader("Expires","-1");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
}
```

I believe I got the suggestion from the following link: http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/03/apache-wicket-force-page-reload-to-fix-ajax-back/